# Fortify AuditWorkbench- Merge audit projects

Tags: static-analysis, fortify

AuditWorkbench has an option *Tools-> Merge Audit Projects*. Looks cool, however, I am still not clear about how to interpret the resulting report.

If I merge two scan reports for the same package scanned say a week apart, how do I know which issues are from the last scan and which ones are fresh?

Because clearly, one would like to Audit only the new issues.

Comment: https://wiki.mobilehealth.va.gov/display/OISSWA/How+to+merge+scan+files

Comment: Thanks @chb that's very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fortify land the preferred solution for merging audit projects is uploading them to the Fortify Server, but you can also use this feature to merge projects. The idea is when you run a new scan you merge the new with the historical old results. The resulting FPR has all of the historical data. If an issue is no longer present in the new scan, ie it was fixed, then the finding goes away. If you want to see the issues identified in the latest scan click the Group By pulldown menu in Audit Work Bench and choose "New". That will show you the new issues.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Fortify Audit Workbench 19 there is a "New issue" in the "group by" dropdown.

[image: Fortify Audit Workbench 19 "New issue" filter]